# WebDriverException: Message: {"errorMessage":"null is not an object

Tags: python, html, selenium, phantomjs

I get the error when executing the following code for [this HTML page](https://topicolist.com/ongoing-ico), but this error only happens at `/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[10]/a/div[1]/div[2]`:

> WebDriverException: Message: {"errorMessage":"null is not an object
>   (near
>   '...ull).singleNodeValue.click();...')","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"223","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:34955","User-Agent":"Python
>   http
>   auth"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"sessionId\":
>   \"ddd5e2d0-10e4-11e8-8645-3d3d785f60f2\", \"args\": [], \"script\":
>   \"window.document.evaluate('/html/body/div[3]/div[1](https://topicolist.com/ongoing-ico)/div[1](https://topicolist.com/ongoing-ico)/div[1](https://topicolist.com/ongoing-ico)/div/div[10]/a/div[1](https://topicolist.com/ongoing-ico)/div[2]',
>   document, null, 9,
>   null).singleNodeValue.click();\"}","url":"/execute","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"execute","directory":"/","path":"/execute","relative":"/execute","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/execute","queryKey":{},"chunks":["execute"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/ddd5e2d0-10e4-11e8-8645-3d3d785f60f2/execute"}}
>   Screenshot: available via screen

This is the code:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.get("https://topicolist.com/ongoing-ico")

num_options = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("w-dyn-item"))
for i in range(num_options):
    xpath = "/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[" + str(i+1) + "]/a/div[1]/div[2]"
    print xpath
    execute_script(driver, xpath)

    project_title = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("heading-49")[0].text.strip()
    print project_title

    time.sleep(10)
    driver.back()

driver.quit()


def execute_script(driver, xpath):
    execute_string = "window.document.evaluate('{}', document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue.click();".format(xpath)

    return driver.execute_script(execute_string)
```

Comment: My guess would be that there are only 9 DIV elements that satisfies the xpath. However I can't prove or disprove it without the page's HTML...

Comment: @GalAbra: Page HTML is given on the 4th line `driver.get("https://topicolist.com/ongoing-ico")`

Answer (score 1):

## A naive solution

You're using one query to count and another to iterate, producing different results. The naive way to solve this is to use the same query to count and iterate.

Which query? That depends on what you want, since your queries select different things (hence the error you're seeing):

1. your CSS query fetches all `.w-dyn-item` elements; but those elements are spread across three `.w-dyn-list` containers—one for `.gold`, one for `.silver`, and one for `.bronze`—and, as it stands,
2. your XPath query only fetches `.w-dyn-item` elements from the first container—`.gold`.

If you want only the `.gold` items, you'll have to adjust your count query:

```py
num_options = len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".w-dyn-list.gold .w-dyn-item"))
# ...
```

If you want all of the items, you'll have to adjust your iteration query:

```py
for i in range(num_options):
    xpath = "/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[" + str(i+1) + "]/a/div[1]/div[2]"
    # ...
```

## A better solution

But you're doing a lot of work just to click an element. You don't need to use JavaScript; Selenium provides [`WebElement#click()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.click) for just this purpose:

```py
items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("w-dyn-item")
for item in items:
    item.find_element_by_xpath("./a/div/[1]/div[2]").click()
```

This is better, but the XPath query is still very specific and inflexible; if anything about the arrangement of the DOM tree in the list item changes, your query will break. Also, the XPath query also doesn't tell me *what* you're trying to click, making it impossible to tell *why* you're trying to click it.

Instead, since you're no longer sending XPath to the browser, you can use another CSS query to better express yourself in a more resilient way:

```py
items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("w-dyn-item")
for item in items:
    item.find_element_by_class_name("description").click()
    # ...
```

Now it's clear that you're trying to click on the description for each item. And because you're not specifying *where* the description appears, the site can change (within reason) without breaking your script.

## The best solution

And by looking even closer at your script, one can see that the only reason you're clicking on the item description is so that you can navigate to the detail page to extract the project title. But that information is already present in the initial list: in the `<h4>` element for each item.

Unless there's additional information you need that doesn't exist on the list page, you don't need to navigate to the detail page. Instead, just find the `<h4>` elements and extract their text:

```py
item_headings = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".w-dyn-item h4")
project_titles = [item_heading.text for item_heading in item_headings]
```

Comment: Upvoting for emphasizing the simple fact _Selenium provides `WebElement#click()` for just this purpose_

Comment: @DebanjanB while its simple and "easy" to use selenium click(). in many cases you should avoid it (unless its E2E tests, and even then..). Its much slower then JS. Another big downside is, that the element must be exposed, otherwise the click wont work.

Comment: This code does not return the list of all projects titles: `items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("w-dyn-item") for item in items:    item.find_element_by_class_name("description").click()`

Comment: @Urban48 If you look into the source code of `WebElement#click()` it is not only _simple and "easy" to use_ but also **powerful, effective and proven**. So while working with _Selenium-Java_ or _Selenium-Python_ clients the first and foremost trial should be with the `WebElement#click()`. Of coarse `WebElement#click()` can **Fail** at times and those juncture we can always resort to _JS Click_.

Comment: @Markus Right. That code is the answer to your question about the error. You'll need the rest of your code to complete your objective. (But if all you really need is the project titles, I added another solution with a better way to get them.)

Comment: No, I need to navigate into each project to extract more info.

Comment: I don't understand this: `item.find_element_by_class_name("description").click()` What is "description"?

Comment: "description" is one of the CSS class names of the element that contain's the list item's description.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the page's HTML that there are only 10 div elements with the xpath

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div
```

While there are 73 elements with the class `w-dyn-item` (no elements have *only* this class).

[image: elements with the mentioned xpath]

**The result is that you try to iterate over 73 elements in an array of 10.**

Comment: So, how can I extract titles of all these 73 projects?

Comment: I assume that I should use `num_options = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("div-block-26"))` and I should also change this `"/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[" + str(i+1) + "]/a/div[1]/div[2]"`.

Comment: I'd use the xpath `//*[contains(@class, \"w-dyn-item\")]` to get all the relevant divs

Comment: Ok, but how can I iterate over it?

Comment: Rather than iterating over a dynamic xpath, try iterating over a list of WebElements: `driver.find_elements_by_class_name("//*[contains(@class, \"w-dyn-item\")]")`

Comment: Could you please elaborate and explain it in the answer. Sorry, I do not get the point and cannot make it working.